# FlutterFlow: RenderBox was not laid out Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterflow

HELPPP! I'm running into a glitch with my FlutterFlow app. When I hit "run," the screen just stays white. Weirdly, though, when I test it through web publishing, everything seems fine.

Also, when I run the code in Android Studio, I'm getting a

> *(RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#db9b4 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
>
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
>
> Failed assertion: line 1965 pos 12: 'hasSize')*

but every container in the app has a defined height !!
[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl3Uz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GL0uh.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTTHz.png)
Error. ‍♂️ Any quick tips on fixing this?

Thanks!

I tried to setup every container height, I didnt use Expanded option because I didnt use any Listview but nothin seems to work